# AVPlayer Buffer Size

Tags: ios, video-streaming, avplayer

I currently have an HLS video stream and I am using `AVPlayer` to play the streamed content on my iPad.

What I am trying to accomplish is the ability to jump back to the start of the stream, pause the stream, and jump back to the current live position of the stream. Kinda like pausing live TV with the DVR for cable.

I have a couple questions:

1) Is this even possible with `AVPlayer`? I have been playing around with `seekTo` and observing `loadedTimeRanges`, and it seems the `seekTo` method doesn't really have good accuracy when jumping back 30 seconds on a stream.

2) How would I increase the `AVPlayer` buffer size to support, let's say a 5 minute rolling window where you can rewind the stream up to 5 minutes, or pause the stream and have it play once the 5 minute rolling window catches up to the paused position.

Any direction/guidance on tackling this problem would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: The problem lies in the m3u playlist. See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2288/_index.html for the 3 types of playlist, and http://www.wowza.com/forums/showthread.php?39253-HLS-Live-Event for the DVR rewind support